# Compare Single Value with comma Separated value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a comma Separated  value need to compare with a single value in SQL Server.

```
yyyyy = 5

DECLARE @sec varchar(max)
SET @sec = '2,3,4,5,6,89,52,36,14,';

SELECT * 
FROM XXX 
WHERE ','+yyyyy+',' LIKE '%' + @sec + '%'
```

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad and the solution is always the same, make from the string a row for every entry and search like you would every normalized table

Comment: You use a string splitting function to split your variable into a table and then use that table with `IN` - example in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). If you don't have a current version of sql server, then simple search the internet for alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below the code requested:

```
DECLARE @sec varchar(max)

SET @sec = '2,3,4,5,6,89,52,36,14,';

;WITH CTE_SEC AS (
    SELECT value AS sec
    FROM 
        STRING_SPLIT(@sec, ',')  
    WHERE 
        RTRIM(value) <> ''
)
SELECT * 
FROM 
    XXX X
    INNER JOIN CTE_SEC C ON C.sec = X.yyyyy
```

[`STRING_SPLIT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function was introduced with SQL Server 2016